# I don't know the passphrase to ubuntu. Is there a way to uninstall ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-environments

I'm trying to restore my Dad's computers to original settings, but Ubuntu gets in the way. As soon as I turn on the computer, Ubuntu comes up and I have no other options. Thx

Comment: You may want to try http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to remove Ubuntu anyway and not keeping any data, you can use the same installation medium you used when installing the current version and then format the hard drive. Then you can choose to install again or go for installing whatever else you like. This is an irreversible action so try it only as a last resort.